# YL 38 moisture sensor

Tags: sensor, soldering, humidity

im well tired of the leds on this sensor and im wondering if i can remove it. I know very little about schematics but i know how to go wild with a solder iron! I found this schematic online and my question is: are they safe to just remove? [image: YL-38 schematic]

Comment: You couldn't even bother to get the first word of the first sentence right! -1 for the sloppiness, and closing since I'm not going to read a question from someone thumbing their nose at us.

Comment: Just looking at the schematic, I can't even guess what purpose you think R5 serves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D1 acts as sort of a pullup on the (open-collector)output of U1A. You can short it out.

If the output is going into a 3.3V system and your module is powered from 5V, you may not want to do that and just black the LED out with some nail polish or a Sharpie. Or add a pullup to the 3.3V and remove the LED.

D2 is just a power indicator LED so you can remove it or (better, I think) remove R4. Or short D2 (which wastes a few mA).

Comment: Wondering what R5 is for....

Comment: @Trevor Other than wasting space and power, maybe to discharge C1 & C2 relatively quickly when the power is interrupted.

Comment: Ya I kinda though that too.. but so many other paths hard to believe it's needed.

Comment: @Trevor It's possible they've given it less thought than we have.

Comment: Good point on the pull-up. THough he would be better leaving it O/C and pulling up at the other end.